# Responsive arrangement of divs with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries

This is what I am trying to accomplish with three div elements:

[image]

How can I do it with flexbox and media queries?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't, or how to make, this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not debugging question. I have a problem which I don't know how to solve. Actually I am not sure that it is possible to solve with the constraints that I have. I am not sure how can I improve my question regarding this. Please advice